# Error when using tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input inside tf.data.Dataset.map

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm having problems with the function **resnet50.preprocess_input()** from **tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet50**

In particular, after several trial and error, I can say the problem comes when inside a dataset generator function, there is a call:

```
dataset.map(pre_processing_image)
```

where

```
def pre_processing_image(image):
    image = resnet50.preprocess_input(image)
    return image
```

and the dataset is splitted in batches. When I reach the last batch, no matter if it is complete or smaller, I get an error similar to

**Tensor("Const:0", shape=(3,), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("BatchDatasetV2:0", shape=(), dtype=variant)**

I can't really understand what is going on because

- If I use another preprocess_input, such as the one of mobilenet, without changing anything else then there is no problem. By digging the code I found that those functions are all calling [this one](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/bc89834ed36935ab4a4994446e34ff81c0d8e1b7/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L18) but mobilenet uses "mode='tf'" while resnet should use 'caffe'
- The error isn't related to the fact the last batch is smaller compared to the others, I tried to make them all equals but the errors keeps happening at the last step of the first epoch of training
- If I don't use **map** but instead **pre_processing_image** is called directly inside **tf.data.Dataset.from_generator** there is no problem.. only the code becomes a lot slower

To give you the full code:

```
def image_gen(ds_path, ds_scores=None):
    for i, path in enumerate(ds_path):
        img = im.load_img(path,
                          color_mode='rgb',
                          target_size=(NETWORK_INFO.value[1],NETWORK_INFO.value[1]),
                          interpolation='bilinear')

        img_to_numpy = np.array(img)

        if (ds_scores is not None):
            yield img_to_numpy, ds_scores[i]
        else:
            yield img_to_numpy

def pre_processing_image(image, score=None):
    image = resnet50.preprocess_input(image)

    if score is None:
        return image
    else:
        return image, score

def generator(batchsize, train=False, val=False, test=False, shuffle=False):
    with tf.Session() as sess:    
        if (train):
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: image_gen(train_paths, train_scores),
                                                      output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32))
        elif(val):
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: image_gen(val_paths, val_scores),
                                                      output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32))
            else:
                dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: image_gen(test_paths),
                                                          output_types=(tf.float32))          

        if (shuffle):
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10*batchsize)            

        dataset = dataset.batch(batchsize)        

        dataset = dataset.map(pre_processing_image,
                                  num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

        dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=2)

        dataset = dataset.repeat(count = -1)        

        iterable = tf.data.make_initializable_iterator(dataset)
        batch = iterable.get_next()
        sess.run(iterable.initializer)

        # yield all the time it is required
        while True:
            try:
                yield sess.run(batch)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                pass
```

I tried to mess with the position of the map function and shuffle/prefatch parameters but nothing solved the issue. Finally as you can see I use the same function for both training and validation generator, I just change the input parameter to selecet with dataset the function should use

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

I tried to search for something similar but regarding other networks that shared the same image preprocessing (such as VGG16) and it comes out those related issues were keras bugs

I updated to the last commit the module keras-applications (commit, not release!) and the code now works without problems